# top does not run

Tags: linux, top

Sorry that I can't be very specific, only symtoms are provided:

- Monday morning
- a CentOS box, 1GB ram, Pentium 4
- web server (thin, rails) does not response (too slow) to a browser of another PC
- ping it, ok
- ssh into it, ok
- a few minutes later, the web server is back to normal speed, serving web requests well
- ping it, ok
- ssh into it, ok
- however, **top** does not run

what should I look at, about this 'top does not run' symptom? thx

Comment: What happens when you try to run top?

Comment: Yeah, we need an error message, or code, or something more than "it doesn't run".

Comment: nothing, just freezed there

Comment: have you figured out what the problem was?

Comment: Not really. However, it's related to _another_ issue. There was an IP address collision on the network (another Windows XP use the same IP address of this server). That's the cause of web server not responding (the browser tries to connects to the XP). After the IP address issue is cleared up, the TOP issue does not happen again.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to strace top and take a look at its output:

strace -f -o strace.out top

You might as well take a look at the shared libraries dependencies with ldd. Maybe libncurses is missing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: have you figured out what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the serve could be swapping furiously would be one thought.  Also, do you have sufficient swap space reserved?

You can 'cat /proc/meminfo' and find these things out.

Comment: # cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:      1026652 kB
MemFree:        307972 kB
Buffers:         54572 kB
Cached:         467120 kB
SwapCached:          0 kB
Active:         292504 kB
Inactive:       319432 kB
HighTotal:      122304 kB
HighFree:          232 kB

Comment: LowTotal:       904348 kB
LowFree:        307740 kB
SwapTotal:     1012084 kB
SwapFree:      1012084 kB
Dirty:            7528 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:       90272 kB

Comment: Mapped:          23280 kB
Slab:            40668 kB
PageTables:       2000 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
CommitLimit:   1525408 kB
Committed_AS:   285288 kB
VmallocTotal:   114680 kB
VmallocUsed:      4576 kB
VmallocChunk:   109684 kB
HugePages_Total:     0
HugePages_Free:      0
HugePages_Rsvd:      0
Hugepagesize:     4096 kB

Comment: run top after meminfo, freeze and no message, ctrl-c can break it though

Answer (score 0):

when you try to run run top; what's the msg it spit out? please copy and paste that msg here..so we can look into it and provide you the result.

Comment: freeze and no message, ctrl-c can break it though

Answer (score 0):

did you try if ps works? for example

```
ps axOpcpu k-pcpu  | head
```

Answer (score 0):

Which top?  That is, run `which top` to make sure you've got what you expect in your path.